# Targeting a <p> with automated classname using Beautiful Soup for web-scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the following HTML:

```
<h2>Address</h2>
<p class="pp-property-price">£$150,000></p>
<p>5 bedroom mansion</p>
```

My Python so far looks and works like the below for the `h2` and the first `<p>`. How can I target the `<p>` that comes after as it doesn't have a classname we can target on Beautiful Soup?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<li class="pp-property-box">
<h2>Address</h2>
<p class="pp-property-price">£$150,000></p>
<p>5 bedroom mansion</p></li>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all("li")

for li in soup.find_all('li', class_="pp-property-box"):
   title = li.find('h2').text
   price = li.find('p', class_="pp-property-price").text
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the next tag after the class `property-price`, then try `find_next`

`li.find('p', class_="pp-property-price").find_next('p').text`

Output: '5 bedroom mansion'